# Assembly: Jump from one section to another

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

In x86 assembly, how can I perform an unconditional jump from one section another?

Eg:

```
.section .text
main:    ...
         jmp here
         ...

.section .another
here:    ...
```

I guess this is a far jump. I get a segfault when trying to run this. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not specify what assembler type (nasm, gas, masm, tasm)

If you know what segment is the the `here` part is, for example, if the `.section` part is in code segment 0x8, then you could do this:

```
jmp 0x8:here
```

You could define the constant to specify the segment and use that also...again your mileage will vary depending on the assembler..

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Also, see here for another way of doing it, push the segment on the stack, push the address of the label on the stack and issue a far return as shown http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398034/inline-assembly-jump-error

Comment: Though keep in mind that issuing a return without a corresponding call is likely going to mess up the internal stack in the branch predictor, which screws with function call performance. You should use a far return to return from a far call, and a far jump otherwise.

Comment: How do you perform a far jump in GAS?

Comment: @TripShock: jmp $0x8:0x1000...see here for a quick reference on far jumps http://sig9.com/articles/att-syntax