# How can adding a function call cause other symbols to become undefined when linking?

Tags: c, assembly, linker, compilation, binutils

I'm hoping someone will be able to help troubleshoot what I think is a linker script issue.

I'm encountering a strange problem after adding a call to a new function. Without the function call, my object files link correctly, however, with the new function call added, I get an undefined reference to a symbol from another object file (I've verified it is actually present using objdump).

Also strangely, with the function call present, if I link all object files first using ld -r (to give a relocatable output) and then using my link script, there are no undefined references, but it seems the link script is being ignored since the output binary does not have the correct entry point.

My (cross-compiler) ld version:

> > i586-elf-ld --version
>       GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.20.1.20100303

My attempts at proving that the 'missing' symbol is present:

> > i586-elf-ld -T link.ld -o kernel32.bin kernel_loader.o main.o stdio.o common.o gdt.o gdt.bin -y putch
>
> ```
> main.o: reference to putch  
> stdio.o: definition of putch  
> main.o: In function `main':  
> main.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `putch'
> ```

N.B. (when I produced this output, I was using a filename of gdt.bin for nasm compiled assembler, it is just another .o file, really)

I can see the symbol that is 'missing' in the appropriate object file:

> > i586-elf-objdump -ht stdio.o
>       stdio.o:     file format elf32-i386
>
> ```
> Sections:
> Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
>   0 .text         000002f9  00000000  00000000  00000034  2**2
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
>   1 .data         0000000c  00000000  00000000  00000330  2**2
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
>   2 .bss          00000008  00000000  00000000  0000033c  2**2
>                   ALLOC
>   3 .comment      00000012  00000000  00000000  0000033c  2**0
>                   CONTENTS, READONLY
> SYMBOL TABLE:
> 00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 stdio.c
> 00000000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
> 00000000 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
> 00000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
> 00000000 l    d  .comment       00000000 .comment
> 00000000 g     F .text  00000016 strlen
> 00000016 g     F .text  0000005c scroll
> 00000008 g     O .data  00000004 numrows
> 00000004 g     O .bss   00000004 ypos
> 00000004 g     O .data  00000004 numcols
> 00000004       O *COM*  00000004 screen_mem
> 00000000         *UND*  00000000 memcpy
> 00000000         *UND*  00000000 memsetw
> 00000072 g     F .text  0000007d newline
> 00000000 g     O .bss   00000004 xpos
> 000000ef g     F .text  0000002e writech
> 00000000 g     O .data  00000004 colour
> 0000011d g     F .text  00000061 cls
> 0000017e g     F .text  00000010 init_video
> 0000018e g     F .text  00000133 putch
> 000002c1 g     F .text  00000037 puts
> 000002f8 g     F .text  00000001 set_text_colour
> ```

And the object file with unresolved reference:

> > i586-elf-objdump -ht main.o
>
> ```
> main.o:     file format elf32-i386
>
> Sections:
> Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
>   0 .text         0000007f  00000000  00000000  00000034  2**2
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
>   1 .data         00000000  00000000  00000000  000000b4  2**2
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
>   2 .bss          00000000  00000000  00000000  000000b4  2**2
>                   ALLOC
>   3 .rodata.str1.1 00000024  00000000  00000000  000000b4  2**0
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
>   4 .comment      00000012  00000000  00000000  000000d8  2**0
>                   CONTENTS, READONLY
> SYMBOL TABLE:
> 00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 main.c
> 00000000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
> 00000000 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
> 00000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
> 00000000 l    d  .rodata.str1.1 00000000 .rodata.str1.1
> 00000000 l    d  .comment       00000000 .comment
> 00000000 g     F .text  0000007f main
> 00000000         *UND*  00000000 init_video
> 00000000         *UND*  00000000 gdt_install
> 00000000         *UND*  00000000 putch
> 00000000         *UND*  00000000 puts
> 00000018       O *COM*  00000001 gdt
> 00000006       O *COM*  00000001 gdtp
> ```

My link script (not sure if it's going to be relevant):

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
ENTRY(start)
phys = 0x00100000;
SECTIONS
{
  .text phys : AT(phys) {
    code = .;
    *(.text)
    *(.rodata*)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
  }
  .data . : AT(data)
  {
    data = .;
    *(.data)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
  }
  .bss . : AT(bss)
  {
    bss = .;
    *(.bss)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
  }
  end = .;
}
```

If I comment out the call to putch in main.c, I instead get undefined references to puts... if I remove the call to gdt_install, no errors!

gdt_install is in the C file, but gdt_install calls a function which is defined in gdt.asm.

```
void gdt_install() {
    /* ... */
    gdt_reset();
}

[bits 32]
[section .text]
global gdt_reset
extern gdtp

gdt_reset:
    lgdt [gdtp]
    mov ax, 0x10      ; 0x10 offset for data segment (sizeof(struct gdt_entry) * 2)
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    jmp 0x08:gdt_reset2   ; 0x08 offset for code segment (sizeof(struct gdt_entry))
gdt_reset2:
    ret              ; ret back to C
```

To try and further diagnose the cause, I've been playing around trying to recreate the errors. If I move the gdt_install() function call to a specific place in the source code, I don't receive any errors and everything works fine:

```
int main() {        

    init_video();

    putch('A');

    puts("<- print a single char there...\n");

    gdt_install();
    puts("asdf\n\n");

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            puts("even\n");
        } else {
            puts("odd\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I move the call above the first puts() call, I receive undefined references for puts!:

```
...
init_video();

putch('A');

gdt_install();

puts("<- print a single char there...\n");

puts("asdf\n\n");

...



i586-elf-ld -T link.ld -o kernel32.bin kernel_loader.o main.o stdio.o common.o gdt.o gdt_asm.o
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `puts'
main.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `puts'
main.c:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `puts'
main.c:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `puts'
```

Next, if I move the call above putch(), it causes a undefined reference to putch (which was where I originally had the call):

```
...
init_video();

gdt_install();

putch('A');

puts("<- print a single char there...\n");

puts("asdf\n\n");

...

main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `putch'
```

And finally, above init_video(), causes a undefined reference to init_video:

```
...
gdt_install();

init_video();

putch('A');

puts("<- print a single char there...\n");

puts("asdf\n\n");

...

main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `init_video'
```

What on earth is causing this error? It's like the gdt_install call is somehow "corrupting" other symbols... I couldn't find any reference to it in any docs, but is there some way that the gdt_install function call could cause some linker "boundary" to be overrun, corrupting other code?

Has anyone encountered a problem like this, or have any ideas as to further investigation? I've posted on the osdev forum: http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=22227 but haven't had much luck.

Thanks

**Edit:**

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but if I omit the link script when linking, all previous errors disappear... (although, then my bootloader cannot call the kernel since it doesn't understand elf binaries).

As requested, here's the main.c file before and after pre-processing and disassembled from the compiled main.o file.

before pre-processing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <common.h>
#include <gdt.h>

int main() {        
    init_video();

    putch('A');

    gdt_install();

    puts("<- print a single char there...\n");

    puts("asdf\n\n");

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            puts("even\n");
        } else {
            puts("odd\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After pre-processing:

```
i586-elf-gcc -Wall -O -fstrength-reduce -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-inline -nostdinc -nostdlib -fsigned-char -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -I./include -E main.c
# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "./include/stdio.h" 1



# 1 "./include/common.h" 1



typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned long ulong;
typedef int size_t;

void *memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n);
void *memset(void *dst, const char val, size_t n);
void *memsetw(void *dst, const ushort val, size_t n);
void *memseti(void *dst, const int val, size_t n);
# 5 "./include/stdio.h" 2

void cls();
void writech(char c);
void putch(char c);
void puts(char *str);
void set_text_colour(uchar f, uchar b);
void init_video();
size_t strlen(char *str);
# 2 "main.c" 2

# 1 "./include/gdt.h" 1





struct gdt_entry {
    ushort limit_low;
    ushort base_low;
    uchar base_middle;
    uchar access;
    uchar granularity;
    uchar base_high;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct gdt_ptr {
    ushort limit;
    uint base;
} __attribute__((packed));

void gdt_set_gate(int n, ulong base, ulong limit, uchar access, uchar gran);
void gdt_install();

extern void gdt_reset();
# 4 "main.c" 2

int main() {
    init_video();

    putch('A');

    gdt_install();

    puts("<- print a single char there...\n");

    puts("asdf\n\n");

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            puts("even\n");
        } else {
            puts("odd\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit, again:**

Thanks to nategoose for suggesting -g3 to give nicer disassembly output:

```
main.o:     file format elf32-i386

SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 main.c
00000000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00000000 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
00000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
00000000 l    d  .rodata.str1.4 00000000 .rodata.str1.4
00000000 l    d  .rodata.str1.1 00000000 .rodata.str1.1
00000000 l    d  .stab  00000000 .stab
00000000 l    d  .stabstr   00000000 .stabstr
00000000 l    d  .comment   00000000 .comment
00000000 g     F .text  0000007f main
00000000         *UND*  00000000 init_video
00000000         *UND*  00000000 putch
00000000         *UND*  00000000 gdt_install
00000000         *UND*  00000000 puts



Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <common.h>
#include <gdt.h>

int main() {        
   0:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
   4:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   7:   ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
   a:   55                      push   %ebp
   b:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   d:   53                      push   %ebx
   e:   51                      push   %ecx
    init_video();
   f:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   10 <main+0x10>

    putch('A');
  14:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
  17:   6a 41                   push   $0x41
  19:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   1a <main+0x1a>

    gdt_install();
  1e:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   1f <main+0x1f>

    puts("<- print a single char there...\n");
  23:   c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
  2a:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   2b <main+0x2b>

    puts("asdf\n\n");
  2f:   c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
  36:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   37 <main+0x37>
  3b:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
  3e:   bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
  43:   f6 c3 01                test   $0x1,%bl
  46:   75 12                   jne    5a <main+0x5a>
            puts("even\n");
  48:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
  4b:   68 07 00 00 00          push   $0x7
  50:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   51 <main+0x51>
  55:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
  58:   eb 10                   jmp    6a <main+0x6a>
        } else {
            puts("odd\n");
  5a:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
  5d:   68 0d 00 00 00          push   $0xd
  62:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   63 <main+0x63>
  67:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp

    puts("asdf\n\n");

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
  6a:   43                      inc    %ebx
  6b:   83 fb 0f                cmp    $0xf,%ebx
  6e:   75 d3                   jne    43 <main+0x43>
            puts("odd\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
  70:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  75:   8d 65 f8                lea    -0x8(%ebp),%esp
  78:   59                      pop    %ecx
  79:   5b                      pop    %ebx
  7a:   5d                      pop    %ebp
  7b:   8d 61 fc                lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
  7e:   c3                      ret
```

And now the new output from a clean make:

```
$ make
nasm -f elf kernel_loader.asm -o kernel_loader.o
i586-elf-gcc -Wall -O0 -fstrength-reduce -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-inline -nostdinc -nostdlib -fsigned-char -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -I./include -g3 -c main.c
i586-elf-gcc -Wall -O0 -fstrength-reduce -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-inline -nostdinc -nostdlib -fsigned-char -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -I./include -g3 -c stdio.c
i586-elf-gcc -Wall -O0 -fstrength-reduce -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-inline -nostdinc -nostdlib -fsigned-char -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -I./include -g3 -c common.c
i586-elf-gcc -Wall -O0 -fstrength-reduce -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-inline -nostdinc -nostdlib -fsigned-char -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -I./include -g3 -c gdt.c
nasm -f elf gdt.asm -o gdt_asm.o
i586-elf-ld -T link.ld -o kernel32.bin -\( kernel_loader.o main.o stdio.o common.o gdt.o gdt_asm.o -\)

main.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/c/programming/os/kernel/main.c:12: undefined reference to `puts'
/cygdrive/c/programming/os/kernel/main.c:14: undefined reference to `puts'
/cygdrive/c/programming/os/kernel/main.c:20: undefined reference to `puts'
/cygdrive/c/programming/os/kernel/main.c:22: undefined reference to `puts'
make: *** [kernel32.bin] Error 1
```

**Edit 3**

As requested, here's the output of nm -s on stdio.o

```
i586-elf-nm -s stdio.o

00000042 T cls
00000000 D colour
00000000 T init_video
         U memcpy
         U memsetw
0000015e T newline
00000004 D numcols
00000008 D numrows
000001e4 T putch
0000024e T puts
00000004 C screen_mem
000000b8 T scroll
00000291 T set_text_colour
00000016 T strlen
00000199 T writech
00000000 B xpos
00000004 B ypos
```

**Edit 4**
As requested, here are the entire source files. I've uploaded the files in a zip to: http://www.owenstephens.co.uk/media/files/kernel.zip Thanks for the continued interest and help, it's much appreciated!

**Makefile:**

```
NASM=nasm
GCC=i586-elf-gcc
LD=i586-elf-ld
FMT=-f elf
GFLAGS=-Wall -O0 -fstrength-reduce -fno-inline -nostdinc -nostdlib -fsigned-char -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -I./include -g3 -c 
LFLAGS=-T link.ld
ALL=kernel_loader.o main.o stdio.o common.o gdt.o gdt_asm.o
INCLUDES=include/stdio.h include/common.h include/gdt.h

all: $(ALL) kernel32.bin

kernel_loader.o: kernel_loader.asm
    $(NASM) $(FMT) $*.asm -o $@

main.o: main.c
    $(GCC) $(GFLAGS) $<

stdio.o: stdio.c include/stdio.h
    $(GCC) $(GFLAGS) $<

common.o: common.c include/common.h
    $(GCC) $(GFLAGS) $<

gdt.o: gdt.c include/gdt.h
    $(GCC) $(GFLAGS) $<

gdt_asm.o: gdt.asm
    $(NASM) $(FMT) $< -o $@

kernel32.bin: $(ALL) $(INCLUDES)
    $(LD) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ -\( $(ALL) -\)

clean:
    rm -f $(ALL) kernel32.bin
```

**Link script:**

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
ENTRY(_start)
phys = 0x00100000;
SECTIONS
{
  .text phys : AT(phys) {
    code = .;
    *(.text)
    *(.rodata*)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
  }
  .data . : AT(data)
  {
    data = .;
    *(.data)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
  }
  .bss . : AT(bss)
  {
    bss = .;
    *(.bss)
    . = ALIGN(4096);
  }
  end = .;
}
```

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <common.h>
#include <gdt.h>

int main() {        
    gdt_install();

    puts("This is a minimal example...");

    return 0;
}
```

**common.c:**

```
#include <common.h>

void *memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n) { return (void *)0; }

void *memset(void *dst, const char val, size_t n) { return (void *)0; }

void *memsetw(void *dst, const ushort val, size_t n) { return (void *)0; }

void *memseti(void *dst, const int val, size_t n) { return (void *)0; }
```

**stdio.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <common.h>

ushort *screen_mem;
int colour = 0x0F;
int xpos = 0, ypos = 0;
int numcols = 80, numrows = 25;

void init_video() {}

size_t strlen(char *str) { return 0; }

void cls() { }

inline void scroll() { }

inline void newline() { }

void writech(char c) { }

void putch(char c) { }

void puts(char *str) { }

void set_text_colour(unsigned char f, unsigned char b){ }
```

**gdt.c:**

```
#include <gdt.h>

struct gdt_entry gdt[3];
struct gdt_ptr gdtp;

void gdt_set_gate(int n, ulong base, ulong limit, uchar access, uchar gran) { }

void gdt_install() { }
```

**gdt.asm:**

```
global gdt_reset

gdt_reset:
    ret
gdt_reset2:
    ret
```

**include/common.h:**

```
#ifndef __COMMON_H
#define __COMMON_H

typedef unsigned short  ushort;
typedef unsigned char   uchar;
typedef unsigned int    uint;
typedef unsigned long   ulong;
typedef int size_t;

void *memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n);
void *memset(void *dst, const char val, size_t n);
void *memsetw(void *dst, const ushort val, size_t n);
void *memseti(void *dst, const int val, size_t n);
#endif
```

**include/stdio.h:**

```
#ifndef __STDIO_H
#define __STDIO_H

#include <common.h>

void cls();
void writech(char c);
void putch(char c);
void puts(char *str);
void set_text_colour(uchar f, uchar b);
void init_video();
size_t strlen(char *str);

#endif
```

**include/gdt.h:**

```
#ifndef __GDT_H
#define __GDT_H

#include <common.h>

struct gdt_entry {
    ushort  limit_low;
    ushort  base_low;
    uchar   base_middle;
    uchar   access;
    uchar   granularity;
    uchar   base_high;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct gdt_ptr {
    ushort limit;
    uint base;
} __attribute__((packed));

void gdt_set_gate(int n, ulong base, ulong limit, uchar access, uchar gran);
void gdt_install();

extern void gdt_reset();

#endif
```

Output of "objdump -t"ing a shared lib that includes all .o files (except the kernel_loader, hence the undefined _start symbol.

```
> i586-elf-objdump -t libos.so.1.0.1

libos.so.1.0.1:     file format elf32-i386

SYMBOL TABLE:
08048080 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
08048162 l    d  .rodata    00000000 .rodata
08049180 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
0804918c l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
00000000 l    d  .stab  00000000 .stab
00000000 l    d  .stabstr   00000000 .stabstr
00000000 l    d  .comment   00000000 .comment
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 main.c
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 stdio.c
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 common.c
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 gdt.c
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 gdt.asm
08048161 l       .text  00000000 gdt_reset2
08049180 g     O .data  00000004 colour
08048125 g     F .text  00000014 memsetw
0804918c g     O .bss   00000004 xpos
08049188 g     O .data  00000004 numrows
08048158 g     F .text  00000005 gdt_install
08048108 g     F .text  0000000a memcpy
080480ee g     F .text  00000005 puts
08049198 g     O .bss   00000018 gdt
08049194 g     O .bss   00000004 screen_mem
080480e0 g     F .text  0000000e putch
08048144 g     F .text  00000014 gdt_set_gate
00000000         *UND*  00000000 _start
08048160 g       .text  00000000 gdt_reset
080480b4 g     F .text  00000005 init_video
080480c8 g     F .text  00000005 scroll
0804918c g       *ABS*  00000000 __bss_start
08048112 g     F .text  00000013 memset
08048080 g     F .text  00000033 main
080480f3 g     F .text  00000014 set_text_colour
080480cd g     F .text  00000005 newline
08049190 g     O .bss   00000004 ypos
080491b0 g     O .bss   00000006 gdtp
0804918c g       *ABS*  00000000 _edata
080491b8 g       *ABS*  00000000 _end
080480c3 g     F .text  00000005 cls
080480b9 g     F .text  0000000a strlen
08048139 g     F .text  0000000a memseti
08049184 g     O .data  00000004 numcols
080480d2 g     F .text  0000000e writech
```

Comment: I did encounter this once, a while ago. I think it had something to do with my libc.a file. Are you sure putch and puts are in your library and that their prototypes in that library match your usage of them?

Comment: +1 This is an extremely well-written question.

Comment: I've implemented my own psuedo-stdio functions (puts, putch...) the functions match exactly - that's the really weird thing, it's only when I add the install_gdt function call that it all breaks down.

Comment: Don't know what this might mean or where it might go, but you say that "gdt_install is in the C file" - but the dump of main.o indicates it's undefined (external to main.o).

Comment: Yes, it is, as I compiled each C file separately. (You'll notice the stdio functions are also undefined). I'm doing a separate link since I want to link using a specific specification (mainly, a flat binary, rather than elf,pe or otherwise). Sorry it's not particularly clear, all ideas are welcome!

Comment: Your linker script sets the entry symbol to `start` - in what file is `start` defined?

Comment: In a small asm script - kernel_loader.asm that is included in the list of link files.

Comment: "colour" is spelled wrong.  Ensure you've got the British version of the library :)

Comment: Nice, I wish it were that, believe me! (I've written all the library functions myself, so at least I can't blame bugs on stupid spelling!)

Comment: What does `stdio.c` look like? Or what's the output of `i586-elf-nm -s stdio.o`?

Comment: I've added the nm output of stdio.o above.

Comment: So stdio.o looks okay. Can you try posting all of your source? Maybe strip out the contents of the functions to the minimum that gets this error. If someone else can duplicate the error, that would make it easier to fix.

Comment: Just for informational purposes, could you build everything except for the initial assembly as a shared library and see if the `objdump -t` of it makes sense with respect to what is and isn't defined in that module?

Comment: @JayM: I've stripped the source files out and it's still erroring. I've included the source files in an edit (I've also zipped them and put them on my site). Thanks!

Comment: @nategoose: I created a shared lib, and it seems all the symbols are defined. I've included the output in case you can spot something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: *"But what's this long face about, Mr. Starbuck; wilt thou not chase the white whale! art not game for Moby Dick?"*

Comment: I downloaded your code and was able to build with no problem. Where did you get your toolchain? What OS are you running?

Comment: Damn, that sucks (in that we've been chasing a toolchain issue!). I'm on Win 7 x64, with a cross-compiler I built from source targeting i586-elf.

Comment: The instructions I followed were these: http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler

I've just tried re-installing, with no luck. Is there any way I can test my gcc/binutils installation/build?

Comment: I built that toolchain and your code still built fine. Here's a couple other things you can try 1) Make sure your source files and linker script have consistent line endings - all CR or all CR/LF. 2) Try building with your native toolchain 3) Try different versions of gcc/binutils

Comment: Hmm, still no luck! 1) Yup, checked all were consistent. Tried changing all to just \n, with no luck. 2) Tried that but hit errors with linking PE files into binary output. 3) Still failed, when using a different version of both gcc and binutils.

Which versions of gcc/binutils worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a circular reference problem on the link line. The linker goes through the object files in order and "remembers" any unresolved externals. However, it also can discard any object files that don't have references to them. If two or more object files reference each other (causing a circular reference), the linker may not be able to track the unresolved entities.

Try duplicating portions of the link line, and then narrow it down to what you need.

```
i586-elf-ld -T link.ld -o kernel32.bin kernel_loader.o main.o stdio.o common.o gdt.o gdt_asm.o \
        stdio.o common.o gdt.o gdt_asm.o
```

Comment: This seems to lead to "multiple definition of <function>" errors and more undefined references to different symbols, so no luck!

Answer (score 2):

The order of files on the command line seems to matter with the GNU linker.  Put the `.o` file containing the entry point (`kernel_loader.o`) first on the command line, then any objects that it directly references, then the objects referenced by those objects (and that aren't already on the cmd-line), etc., or it's possible that the linker will miss some files.

Comment: Aha! I was hoping someone else would suggest this, I had thought that I'd fixed the problem this way. I don't know whether it's some sort of circular-reference-style issue, but after rearranging I'd get into the situation where moving/calling functions caused the link to fail again...

Comment: Yes, this appears to work. If I order the object files in the order of their inclusion (and then their functions being called) it appears to work... However, when I move the problematic gdt_install call to the top of the main.c source file, I get undefined references.

Comment: Try putting the object files (other than the entry point) into an archive with (`rm -f libfoo.a ; ar -cr libfoo.a a.o b.o c.o ; ranlib libfoo.a`), then linking against `libfoo.a` instead of the individual object files.

Comment: Argh, no! It still errors, claiming a undefined reference, as before.

Comment: Try wrapping the object file list in -Wl,-( and -Wl,-) (you may need to backslash-escape the parentheses).

Comment: I've never seen those link options before, they appear as if they should fix the issue. However, I'm getting an error from ld: "kernel_lib.a, could not read symbols: Bad value" Googling seems to suggest it could be some sort of 64-bit only issue (I'm on Win 7 x64, but I'm using my cross compiler targeting elf32-i386, if that helps). 
Any suggestions?

Comment: I also tried with the object file list, as per your suggestion. It gives the same undefined reference error, unfortunately.

Comment: @owst: If all else fails, you can try function-per-file style, probably coupled with the archive method I suggested in an earlier comment.

Comment: I'll give it a go. Could you explain your reasoning behind it though (so I know what, if anything I'm looking for!)? What would the archive method do, that isn't done when using separate object files?
Also, which functions do you suggest placing in separate files, all of them? 
Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: @owst: operating under the assumption that what you ultimately want is for your linker to work reliably, rather than to completely understand what's going on (which I still can't completely explain, though I have some idea), the objective is to simplify the linker's task.  The linker links code at object-file granularity, so if you have two functions in an object, only one of which is used, the linker will still scan for unresolved references from the other function, and give errors if any of those references can't be resolved.  By using file-per-function, you don't get that effect.

Comment: Also, the reason for putting the objects into an archive is so that the linker can essentially ignore any order issues on the command-line itself - your .o file for the entry point precedes the .a file containing all your library routines on the cmd line, so the linker has the ability to scan for .o files from the archive as required, instead of only scanning forward through .o files on the cmd line. (I had thought that using the archive would have fixed your problem before, but was evidently wrong.) Coupling file-per-function with the .a file, you shouldn't need to worry about cmd line order.

Comment: Yes, you're right that I do want it to work! :) Of course it's always better to actually understand why and how the fix works, but I'm not necessarily fussed in this case...

I'll try your suggestions after work today, and see how it goes. Thanks for the all the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398034/inline-assembly-jump-error) (may be similar/identical, I'm not sure) which covers some of this. Does that one offer any help?

Comment: That looks like the code is from a similar (if not the same) tutorial. I'll check it out, thanks. One difference is that his error is at runtime, whereas mine is link-time... but we'll see :)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar problems a few times and at a certain point, just before I go stark raving mad, I start to look for invisible things that might end up in the names.  Non-ASCII bytes or non-printable ASCII characters that could have snuck into your source code and attached themselves to the first code seen after `gdt_install();`

You might want to try adding a comment or empty macro (or a `do{}while(0)` ) between your call to `gdt_install()` and the next real line of code.  Maybe even go as far as placing your cursor in the function name and back it up to just before the first character of that function name and start typing whatever you decide to add there.  If it is something caused by the presence of `gdt_install();` then something else getting thrown in there should force a different error.

If you haven't already, you may want to view the preprocessor output of the file with the call to `gdt_install()` as well as its assembly output.

If none of that produces anything interesting, change the name of `gdt_install` and see if that changes anything.  I've seen a few instances where bugs in the compiler and/or linker could produce something odd like this.  Perhaps a bug in a hash table used as a symbol table (maybe even in the elf file's hash table).

Hope you figure this out.

Comment: Nice idea regarding non-ascii characters; unfortunately I couldn't spot any. Changing the name didn't cause different behaviour.

I'll add (in an edit) the preprocessor and assembly output for the file with the problematic call.
Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: gcc's assembly output would probably have been more readable with respect to labels.

Comment: @owst: Try adding `-g3` to your compile commands and see if the linker errors change any.  ld uses debug symbols to generate errors that are more tied to the source code.  You can always strip the binary after the build.  Also, if you haven't already you might try to build with `-O0` just for the error output.

Comment: The linker errors are now more descriptive (now using filename/line instead of offsets) but they appear to be showing the same error message. I was using -O which I thought was the same as -O0, but I've tried that too, just in case. 

There doesn't seem to be much difference in the output generated...

Comment: @owst: `-O` is the same as `-O1`.

Answer (score 0):

some wild guess, perhaps your assembler function which is called (and probably inlined) in `gdt_install` is messing up what is coming after it. (this jump at the end before the `ret` is unusual, never seen that)

Is your `gdt_install` in the same compilation unit as where you have the call? Do you use `-O[12]` for compilation? Is the call inlined? How does the assembler that the compiler produces for the call side look like?

Did you try to compile with `-O0 -g` or `-fno-inline` (or how this option is called)?

Comment: The jump is used to "install" the correct CS register value (the code descriptor). I don't think that the assembler function could be inlined, since it's separately compiled (with Nasm), although I could well be wrong. I've already got all optimisation and inlining disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote. "`I've implemented my own psuedo-stdio functions (puts, putch...) the functions match exactly ...`" Are you using anything in the standard libc? If you aren't, you should add `-nostdlib` to your command line. I have seen strange things happen when I've tried to override functions in the standard libc.

Comment: Nope, I'm not using anything from std libc; I've got that flag already. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that perhaps the combining of the linking symbol tables from the nasm generated object and the gcc/gas generated objects might be messing something up.

Could you try replacing the call to `gtd_install` with a call to a short inline function containing inline assembly that calls or jumps to `gtd_install` and resides in the same file as the current call to `gtd_install`?

Another thing that just popped into my mind is that if `gtd_install` is written in assembly language then it is possible that it might not be 100% syntactically correct.  I've never seen anything like this, but just thinking that it might be possible that `gtd_install`'s boundaries (particularly the end) or its size is not correctly determined by the assembler, and that is just having random-ish results.

Baring that I think you're going to have to go to the binutils folks and ask them for help directly.